# kerberos ENC-TC

Tags: kerberos

What is wrong with the heimdal configuration?

## kinit test

test@REALM's Password:
kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: No ENC-TS found

An /etc/krb5.conf contains:
        default_tgs_enctypes = des-cbc-crc
        default_tkt_enctypes = des-cbc-crc
        default_etypes = des-cbc-crc
        default_etypes_des = des-cbc-crc
        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really didn't provide much info.
I suggest showing us the output of `klist` both before and after `kinit`.

But as best I can determine: ENC-TS is the encrypted TimeStamp used in pre-authentication.
For whatever reason, the server is not including the ENC-TS section of the Kerberos response.

The section of `krb5.conf` that you shared does not seem related to this pre-authentication setting.

Comment: I am using LDAP as a backend for heimdal.

I can provide krb5 config if it can help...

klist shows in both cases:
klist: No ticket file: /tmp/krb5cc_0

kinit fails with incorrect password and says "kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: No ENC-TS found" for correct one ...

Comment: Thank you! I have found the "root of evil".

It was due to incorrect real minitialisation. Heimdal has not stored his accounts (krbtgt/REALM etc) into LDAP.

The solution is to reinit the realm from scratch (kasmin -l; init REALM).